# How to split a R loop on several nodes with Slurm?

Tags: r, slurm

I have a R (RHO_COR.R) script and I would like to create a loop in order to split the jobs on several nodes.

I show the part of the script where I would like to create the loop.

```
res <- foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(combs)) %dopar% {
 G1 <- split[[combs[i,1]]]
 G2 <- split[[combs[i,2]]]
 dat.i <- cbind(data[,G1], data[,G2])
 rho.i <- cor_rho(dat.i)
}
```

The different results of `res` are stored in several files.
`combs` is a vector which looks like this (but it can change, according to my input file) :

```
> combs
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    4
 [7,]    2    5
 [8,]    3    4
 [9,]    3    5
[10,]    4    5
```

I would like to send each row of `combs` on a node.

This is my slurm code :

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o job-%A_task.out
#SBATCH --job-name=paral_cor
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=126G  
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=32

#Set up whatever package we need to run with

module load gcc/8.1.0 openblas/0.3.3 R

# SET UP DIRECTORIES

OUTPUT="$HOME"/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_parallel_nodes_test
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

export FILENAME=~/RHO_COR.R

#Run the program

Rscript $FILENAME > "$OUTPUT"
```

I do not want to use arrays. I wonder if I create an argument which is `seq_len(nrow(combs)`  could be a solution ?

```
for i in my_argument
 do Rscript $FILENAME -i > "$OUTPUT"
done
```